# What do B+ and C+ mean on the wires of a Lifepo4 battery pack?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, charger, lithium, lifepo4

I bought [this Lifepo4 battery pack](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/lifepo4-battery-pack-24v-10ah/900478001.html). It came with its own charger. The seller told me the charger can be connected directly to the battery.

There are 4 cables coming out of the battery: C+, C-, B+ and B-. Both C and B have 26.6 volts.

I understand that C means Charger and B means Battery.

When I connected the charger (not plugged into the wall socket) to the C cables, there was a huge spark.

I am totally lost as what C and B really mean. The seller doesn't answer me anymore. Does anyone have an idea?

Also, is it normal that there was a huge spark when I connected the charger? (The fuse on the charger didn't burn).

Comment: Here's an idea.  Look for a different battery pack that comes with an adequate datasheet.  No datasheet => no sale.

Comment: Mistake number one: ordering anything off Alibaba/Aliexpress.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like C+/C- is for putting current into the battery pack (connect to charger), and B+/B- is for getting current out of the battery pack (connect to load).  Presumably there is some circuitry inside the pack which handles limiting the charging current, cell balancing, over/undervoltage protection, safety, and so on.  But, it's possible that some or all of that circuitry is missing or isn't designed well.

The issue with sparking could be that if you connect an unplugged charger, they may not have designed in adequate protection against current flowing "backwards" from the battery to the charger, e.g. the battery is charging up discharged output capacitors in the charger, or potentially much worse things happening that could fry the charger, draw too much current from the battery, etc. They may expect you to plug the charger to wall power before attaching the battery.  Or they may expect the opposite - really it should either specify in the data sheet, or work properly regardless of what order you connect things.

Could be they did a good job of the design and didn't provide adequate documentation.  Could be they did a bad job, and the product should be used with care or even mistrust (or not at all).  If there's no way to get more information from the vendor then your options are: try it some different ways and see what works (dispose of it if fried), or disassemble it and figure out how it's designed, possibly having to buy another one to use once you understand it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The charger came with a user guide saying to plug it 1st to the battery and then to the wall socket. As this is a lithuim battery, I'm afraid it explodes or starts a fire :S